# Barryvdh/laravel-domPDF returning Attempt to read property "name" on bool

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, barryvdh

Im using Laravel 8 with PHP 8 as well as barryvdh/laravel-domPDF. I have a crud that displays employee information and you can print out their payslips. When i dont pass through the $id it works correctly and prints all the employees information however when i do it returns the error:

> Attempt to read property "name" on bool

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/print/{id}', ['App\Http\Livewire\EmployeesTable', 'print'])->name('livewire.employees-table.print');
```

This is my model function

```
  public function print($id){
  $employees = Employees::find($id);
  $teams= Team::all();
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('employees.payslip', compact('teams', 'employees'));
  return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}
```

This is my user relationship:

```
  public function employees(){
  return $this->hasMany(Employees::class);
}
```

This is my employees relationship:

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

.

```
<thead>
 @foreach ($employees as $employee)
 <tr>
   <td>
   {{$employee->name}} {{$employee->surname}}
   {{$employee->phone}}
   {{$employee->role}}
 </td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
</thead>
<thead>
 @foreach ($teams as $team)
 <tr>
   <td>
   {{$team->companyName}}
   {{$team->street}}
   {{$team->compound}}
   {$team->suburb}}
   {$team->phone}}
 </td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Hos is this even related to [tag:dompdf]? This looks like a pure templating issue

Answer (score 1):

I think  `$employees` return empty result so better check before looping

```
@if(isset($employees)&&count((array)$employees))
 @foreach ($employees as $employee)
 <tr>
   <td>
   {{$employee->name}} {{$employee->surname}}
   {{$employee->phone}}
   {{$employee->role}}
 </td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
@endif
```